# Show data in table based on dropdown selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Eg :
Table Data : [{user : "name 1",value : "value 1"},{user : "name", value : "value 2"},{user : "name 2", value: "value 1"}]

Dropdown value : ['value 1','value 2', 'value 3']

Lets say if dropdown value is selected as value 1 then it should display name 1 and name 2 in the table

Comment: please add more details to your question, what do you want to achieve? some code maybe..

Comment: Basically it is an kind of filter option where it should display data based on selected value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tableData = [{user : "name 1",value : "value 1"},{user : "name", value : "value 2"},{user : "name 2", value: "value 1"}]

const getTableData = (tableData, dropdownValue) => tableData.filter(item => item.value.toLowerCase() === dropdownValue.toLowerCase())

console.log(getTableData(tableData, 'value 1'))
```

You may use that function to filter out your data.
A simple react component for the same would look like this.

```
const ShowTableData = ({tableData, dropdownValue}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const getTableData = (tableData, dropdownValue) => 
                    tableData.filter(
                              item => 
                              item.value.toLowerCase() === dropdownValue.toLowerCase()
                         )

    useEffect(() => {
        setData(getTableData(tableData, dropdownValue))
    },[tableData, dropdownValue])
    return (
    <table>
        <tbody> 
            {
            data.map(item => (
                     <tr key={item.name}>
                         <td> 
                             {item.name} 
                         </td> 
                     </tr>
                    )
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    )
}
```

Comment: There should be dropdown. If dropvalue is set to user1 then it should display data of all user1 in table. If dropdown value is set to user2 then it should display data of user2 in table